# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(?)' Dash Plotly Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am creating a dashbaoard and using xlsx file as data source. Dashbaord has two inputs and one output.
Inputs are

1. Dropdown
2. Radio Button

Output is

1. Treemap

The output works fine for some of the dropdown options and raises following error for few options

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(?)'
```

my code is as below.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

vault= pd.read_excel('Single Date BNV & CNV.xlsx')
vault['Deposit Date']= vault['Deposit Date'].dt.date

app = dash.Dash()
head = html.H1('WELCOME TO DASHBOARD')
head_style ={'textAlign':'center'}

c_bank = vault['Bank'].unique()
cb_banks = dcc.Dropdown(id='bank_dd',
    options=[{"label": bank, "value": bank} for bank in c_bank],
    multi=True,
    placeholder="Select a Bank",
    style={'width':'500px','margin':'5px'}) 


color_options = ['Deposit Date','Denom']
color_option = dcc.RadioItems(id='color_option1',
                options=[{"label": color, "value": color} for color in color_options],
                              value='Denom',
                style={'width':'500px','margin':'5px','label':'Color by'},
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'},)


tm1 = dcc.Graph(id='tm1')

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='tm1', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='bank_dd', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='color_option1', component_property='value')])


def update_figure(selected_bank,color):

    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].isin(selected_bank)]
    fig = px.treemap(filtered_bank, path=['Vault', 'Bank', 'Category','Denom','Design','Safe ID','Value'], values='Pieces',
                 color=color,title='Deep Dive') 

    return fig

app.layout = html.Div([
                       html.Div([head],style=head_style),
                       
                       html.Div([cb_banks,
                                 html.Label(['Color By:']),
                                 color_option]),
                       html.Div([tm1]),   
                                ],)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

The command `.info()` produces following result.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1126 entries, 0 to 1125
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   Safe ID       1126 non-null   int64  
 1   Deposit Date  1126 non-null   object 
 2   Bank          1126 non-null   object 
 3   Category      1126 non-null   object 
 4   Denom         1126 non-null   int64  
 5   Pieces        1126 non-null   int64  
 6   Value         1126 non-null   int64  
 7   Vault         1126 non-null   object 
 8   Design        1126 non-null   object 
 9   Bundles       1126 non-null   float64
 10  Type          1126 non-null   object 
 11  Report Date   1126 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(4), object(7)
memory usage: 105.7+ KB
```

The objection i get when I run the app

```
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 9, in update_figure
    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].isin(selected_bank)]
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4294, in isin
    result = algorithms.isin(self, values)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 410, in isin
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 9, in update_figure
    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].isin(selected_bank)]
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4294, in isin
    result = algorithms.isin(self, values)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 410, in isin
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 9, in update_figure
    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].isin(selected_bank)]
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4294, in isin
    result = algorithms.isin(self, values)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 410, in isin
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 9, in update_figure
    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].isin(selected_bank)]
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4294, in isin
    result = algorithms.isin(self, values)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 410, in isin
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 9, in update_figure
    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].isin(selected_bank)]
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4294, in isin
    result = algorithms.isin(self, values)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 410, in isin
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 9, in update_figure
    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].isin(selected_bank)]
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4294, in isin
    result = algorithms.isin(self, values)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 410, in isin
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 9, in update_figure
    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].isin(selected_bank)]
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4294, in isin
    result = algorithms.isin(self, values)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 410, in isin
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2021 10:47:43] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

After changing the dropdown. The following objection is raised.

```
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 10, in update_figure
    fig = px.treemap(filtered_bank, path=['Vault', 'Bank', 'Category','Denom','Design','Safe ID','Value'], values='Pieces',
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py", line 1464, in treemap
    return make_figure(
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1826, in make_figure
    args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)
     dfg = df.groupby(path[i:]).agg(agg_f)
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 370, in _agg_1dim
    return colg.aggregate(how)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 262, in aggregate
    return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 933, in _python_agg_general
    output[key] = self._try_cast(result, obj, numeric_only=True)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 822, in _try_cast
    result = maybe_downcast_to_dtype(result, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 135, in maybe_downcast_to_dtype
    converted = maybe_downcast_numeric(result, dtype, do_round)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 222, in maybe_downcast_numeric
    new_result = trans(result).astype(dtype)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(?)'
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 10, in update_figure
    fig = px.treemap(filtered_bank, path=['Vault', 'Bank', 'Category','Denom','Design','Safe ID','Value'], values='Pieces',
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py", line 1464, in treemap
    return make_figure(
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1826, in make_figure
    args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1547, in process_dataframe_hierarchy
    dfg = df.groupby(path[i:]).agg(agg_f)
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
    fig = px.treemap(filtered_bank, path=['Vault', 'Bank', 'Category','Denom','Design','Safe ID','Value'], values='Pieces',
    dfg = df.groupby(path[i:]).agg(agg_f)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 928, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 222, in maybe_downcast_numeric
    new_result = trans(result).astype(dtype)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(?)'

Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    fig = px.treemap(filtered_bank, path=['Vault', 'Bank', 'Category','Denom','Design','Safe ID','Value'], values='Pieces',
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py", line 1464, in treemap
    return make_figure(
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1826, in make_figure
    args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1547, in process_dataframe_hierarchy
    dfg = df.groupby(path[i:]).agg(agg_f)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 928, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 419, in _aggregate
    result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 386, in _agg
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 370, in _agg_1dim
    return colg.aggregate(how)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 262, in aggregate
    return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 933, in _python_agg_general
    output[key] = self._try_cast(result, obj, numeric_only=True)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 822, in _try_cast
    result = maybe_downcast_to_dtype(result, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 135, in maybe_downcast_to_dtype
    converted = maybe_downcast_numeric(result, dtype, do_round)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 222, in maybe_downcast_numeric
    new_result = trans(result).astype(dtype)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(?)'
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 10, in update_figure
    fig = px.treemap(filtered_bank, path=['Vault', 'Bank', 'Category','Denom','Design','Safe ID','Value'], values='Pieces',
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py", line 1464, in treemap
    return make_figure(
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1826, in make_figure
    args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1547, in process_dataframe_hierarchy
    dfg = df.groupby(path[i:]).agg(agg_f)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 928, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 419, in _aggregate
    result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 386, in _agg
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 370, in _agg_1dim
    return colg.aggregate(how)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 262, in aggregate
    return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 933, in _python_agg_general
    output[key] = self._try_cast(result, obj, numeric_only=True)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 822, in _try_cast
    result = maybe_downcast_to_dtype(result, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 135, in maybe_downcast_to_dtype
    converted = maybe_downcast_numeric(result, dtype, do_round)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 222, in maybe_downcast_numeric
    new_result = trans(result).astype(dtype)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(?)'
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "<ipython-input-77-90f281174c76>", line 10, in update_figure
    fig = px.treemap(filtered_bank, path=['Vault', 'Bank', 'Category','Denom','Design','Safe ID','Value'], values='Pieces',
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 222, in maybe_downcast_numeric
    new_result = trans(result).astype(dtype)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(?)'

Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    converted = maybe_downcast_numeric(result, dtype, do_round)
  File "C:\Users\Husnain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 222, in maybe_downcast_numeric
    new_result = trans(result).astype(dtype)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(?)'

127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2021 10:50:08] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The app stays live and works for few options.

Comment: You have the string `(?)` in a field that's supposed to contain an integer.

Comment: I cant figure out where exactly

Comment: Post the full traceback of the error. And can you format the code without all those blank lines and useless `# In[XX]` comments?

Comment: I have updated the code and pasted the traceback. Traceback cant be fully added due to limitations of length

Comment: Supposing your DataFrame is `df`, to get where that `(?)` is you can do `[df[df[col]=='(?)'] for col in df.columns]`

Comment: It returned an empty data frame

Comment: It isn't the column name that has the string, it's one of the values in that column. Looks like the `Bank` column. You could `print(df['Bank'])` to see its values.

Answer (score 0):

**For future reference**: I saw the same error with a [Sunburst chart](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/), it turns out that I forgot to set the `values` parameter which should be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exception when plotting a Plotly Treemap within a Streamlit app, which uses a drop-down to filter what to display. Selecting some values worked, but others threw the same exact ValueError. It took me a quite few days of investigation when I noticed this appears to be caused by function `aggregate`  within pandas, and not to do with Plotly. My pandas version was 1.1.0. Upgrading pandas to 1.3.0 or later resolved it for me.